# Send a local push notification based on condition

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, push-notification

I'm struggling with sending local push notification in ionic. I have followed [this](http://digitaldrummerj.me/ionic-local-notification/) tutorial which places all the code related to local push notification inside controller. But my template variables are not rendered properly in my browser as well as device..

On browser it shows,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugins' of undefined
    at Object.schedule (http://localhost:8100/lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js:8:30084)
    at Scope.$scope.scheduleInstantNotification
```

How do I schedule a local push notification when particular condition mets?

Comment: try after adding local-notification.js in your index.html

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya really? where this file exists?

Comment: plugin/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/www

Comment: pls mention the full path..

Comment: you can find plugin folder in your root directory of project

Comment: ya, find that file. Where I need to add that? after `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` line?

Comment: copy that file in www/js and link that line after cordova.js

Comment: No result :( still my template vars are not rendered.

Comment: and make sure you are running on deivce..this will not works in browser

Comment: ya,, tested in my device also.. still no result..  But I do like this https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/issues/1022 inside ionic.run function, it works.. BUt I want the local notification to schedule on particular condition.

Comment: I'm struggling about this for 1 day,  doc is really poor..

Comment: okey, then put your code inside deviceready function

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya do you know how to invoke a function which exists on deviceReady?

Comment: pls help,,, tried all the options..

Comment: just write your notification code as follow

*document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
   /*Your code here*/

}, false);*

Comment: I already done that.. pls provide a sample github code which has implemented local push notif

Comment: we are not here to write code for you

Comment: sorry, i'm asking for link..

Comment: https://devdactic.com/local-notifications-ionic/

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya tried that also... :(